# How to stop react-native from auto updating the packages? When trying to rebuild the app after two years with same code it show packages depricated

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install, npm-package

The react-native app build in 2019. After some years I am trying to rebuild the same app nothing changed in the code not NPM not in react-native version but it still show packages deprecated.

How to stop auto update packages.
How to rebuild the same app without any changes.

Comment: Is there a caret ^ sign before the package version number.?

Comment: Yes there is ^ sign before some of the packages version.

Comment: can you cross-check that the caret ^ sign package has only been updated is that correct.?

Answer (score 0):

remove ^ icon in package.json file any package version.
example: "react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
removed: "react-native-phone-number-input": "2.1.0",

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).